# How can I rewrite drupal page metatags from within a Rules module action?

Tags: drupal-7, meta-tags

I am trying to detect when a content-type node is updated or saved for the first time and has attached audio.

If this is the case I want to re-write the Twitter Card meta tags to turn an image card into a media card and then include a link to the relevant audio field to complete the media card and player options.

I have a rule set that detects the creation / update of a node; I can screen for nodes of the correct "type", and my rule fires appropriately, but I am failing on my rule action to re-write the meta tags.

Rules tells me that $node is available to me, so I've been trying to do:

```
$node->metatags[LANGUAGE_NONE]['description']['value'] = 'Some description.';
$node->metatags[LANGUAGE_NONE]['title']['value'] = 'Some title | ZZZ';
```

This I have followed by an "entity save" action. My rationale is to write the changes before the recursion lock kicks in and stops the rule executing.

I've been going round the houses for a day trying to solve this. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't fully understand your requirement. But you can easily update your node datas using hook_node_presave (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) before node is being saved in to database.

Use hook_node_insert(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x) and hook_node_update(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x) if you need to do the same thing after the node is saved in to database

Comment: Thank you; can I call these as an action from within Rules? The reason for doing this in this long-winded way is that people may not add audio required for a media card to a node initially. Instead, they may add that audio later. This means I need a way to react to the change and re-write the metatags appropriately.

Comment: You cannot use those function within the rules. hook_node_update should be the right fit for your needs. But you have to write a custom module and call these function from there.